# Facebook bot with multiple senders

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to make a Facebook bot look like there are multiple senders from the bot side? I couldn't see anything obvious in the Facebook docs. Even if the icon for the bot could be changed on the fly that may work

I'm trying to make a Facebook chat bot where a different 'person' will reply based on user input

**EDIT:**

As an alternative approach, could it be possible to use two separate facebook bots to have a semi simultaneous conversation with a single user. Take an example scenario where user starts a conversation with Bot A, then midway through the conversation, Bot B in a separate Facebook messenger chat, messages the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Messenger Bots are subscribed to individual Facebook Pages, so there is no way to have multiple users.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do it currently;

- For each Facebook Page, Facebook generates a unique id for the user(User#X has different id for PageA and PageB).
- For each App(Bot) Facebook creates a unique id for the User#X(User#X will have different id for App#1 and App#1 for the same Facebook page)